# Jinja for loop is not working after adding qs to iterator. Django

Tags: django, django-filter

In my project I am using django-filter and when I am adding .qs to `{% for product in products %}` `{% for product in products.qs %}`. In the template result filters are displaying, but products are not. Here are my files.

**html**

```
    <form method="get">
        {{ filterA.form.as_p }}
        {{ filterB.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Press" class="filter-go">
    </form>
```

```
{% for product in products.qs %}
<div class="product" onclick="location.href='{% url 'items' product.id %}'">
    <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Img is not found (">
    <p class="product-title">{{ product.title }}</p>
    <b><p class="product-price">{{ product.price }} &#8381;</p></b>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    con = {
        'services': Service.objects.all(),
        'products': Product.objects.all(),
        'galery': GaleryImage.objects.all(),
        'product_types': Category.objects.all(),
        'filterA': FilterA(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all()),
        'filterB': FilterB(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all()),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', con)

def product(request, pk=None):
    try: 
        a = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    except:
        return render(request, 'error404.html')

    context = {
        'id': pk,
        'product': a,
    }
    return render(request, 'product.html', context)
```

**filters.py**

```
class FilterA(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category']

class FilterB(django_filters.FilterSet):
    CHOICES = (
        ('ascending', 'По дате (А-Я)'),
        ('descending', 'По дате (Я-А)'),
    )
    CHOICES2 = (
        ('price_low', 'По цене по возрастанию'),
        ('price_high', 'По цене по убыванию'),
    )

    orderDate = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, method='filter_by_date', label='')
    orderPrice = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES2, method='filter_by_price', label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'price': ['lt', 'gt'],
        }
    
    def filter_by_date(self, queryset, name, value):
        expr = 'date' if value == 'ascending' else '-date'
        return queryset.order_by(expr)

    def filter_by_price(self, queryset, name, value):
        expr = 'price' if value == 'price_low' else '-price'
        return queryset.order_by(expr)
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Կատեգորիա', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, verbose_name='Ապրանքի վեռնագիրը')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Նկարագրություն', null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_img', verbose_name='Նկարը')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Գին')
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Ամսաթիվը որի ժամանակ ստեղծվել է')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: What is `products.qs` supposed to do?

Comment: I Ive watched a django-filter tutorial and I saw it on it. Do you want link?

Comment: Where do you even pass `products` to the template?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're expecting `products.qs` to do some filtering as per some logic from `django-filter`. However, your template's context variable for `"products"` is a simple queryset. You likely need to use `{% for product in filterA.qs %}` or `{% for product in filterB.qs %}` depending on which filtering you'd like to use.

Comment: Oh I am blind, Ive wroted products insteam of productsA or B XD. Thank you do I have to delete this question or can be kinda helpful for someone?

Comment: We've all been there, it's part of learning.

Comment: I will up your answer and tomorow delete it.